# Simplification of a function of two variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone help me how to prove that function

$$
\begin{split}
f(x,k)=&(54k)x^5 \\
&-(108k^2-63k+27) x^4 \\
&+(72k^3-150k^2+72k-11) x^3 \\
&-(20k^4-106k^3+105k^2-57k+9) x^2\\
&+(2k^5-30k^4+46k^3-51k^2+52k-17)x\\
&+\left(3k^5-6k^4+11k^3-18k^2+6k \right)
\end{split}
$$

is always positive, where $x \ge 1$ and $k\in(0,\frac{1}{2}]$? What do I need to consider? I've tried to simplify $f(x,k)$ to an expression $(x-1)...$ (because of $x \ge 1$), but $f(x,k)$ is complicated. Also, $f(x,k)$ has at least one real root, because of the $x^5$ term.

Comment: In what context did this function arise, why do you think it should be true? Also have you tried some values? It seems that $f(1,1/2)<0$ for example.

Comment: I have graphed it. It is false for k less than 0.35, approximately. Anyway this is the function centered in $x = 1$, $54 k (x-1)^5+\left(-108 k^2+333 k-27\right) (x-1)^4+\left(72 k^3-582 k^2+864 k-119\right) (x-1)^3+\left(-20 k^4+322 k^3-1203 k^2+1191 k-204\right) (x-1)^2+\left(2 k^5-70 k^4+474 k^3-1143 k^2+904 k-176\right) (x-1)+5 k^5-56 k^4-432 k^2+235 k^3+304 k-64$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{k \to 0}f(x,k) = -27x^4-11x^3-9x^2-17x$$

In particular,

$$\lim_{k \to 0}f(1,k) = -27-11-9-17<0$$

Hence it can't be always positive over the claimed domain as polynomial is continuous.